# Pandas Series Histogram - How make subplots show up on separate graphs?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am trying out the Titanic ML competition on Kaggle, and want to try to plot histograms of two separate pieces of information, on two separate histograms.  However, the code below plots everything on one histogram, as seen in the picture below (blue being cb, and orange being qt).

For reference, the datatype of cb and qt is matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot.

Is there a way I can get cb and qt to be on two separate histograms?
Thank you in advance!

```
cb = cherbourg.loc[cherbourg.Survived == 1].Pclass.hist()
cb.set_xlabel('Pclass')
cb.set_ylabel('No. Survivors')
cb.set_title('Number of Survivors From Cherbourg By SES')

qt = queenstown.loc[queenstown.Survived == 1].Pclass.hist()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select the unique towns and plot them
- Histogram is not the correct type of plot. These are categorical [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# load the dataframe
df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

# set the column to a Categorical type: optional
df.pclass = pd.Categorical(df.pclass, categories=[1, 2, 3], ordered=True)

# plot
for town in df.embark_town.unique():
    data = df[(df.embark_town == town) & df.survived == 1]
    if not data.empty:
        plt.figure(figsize=(6, 3))
        data.pclass.value_counts(sort=False).plot(kind='bar')
        plt.xlabel('Pclass')
        plt.ylabel('No. Survivors')
        plt.title(f'Number of Survivors From {town}')
```

[image]

### [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html)

- Specify `row='embark_town'` instead of `col='embark_town'` to have a single column of plots
- Using [`seaborn.countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html#seaborn-countplot)

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# select data
df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
data = df[df.survived == 1]

# plot
g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col='embark_town', height=5)
g.map(sns.countplot, 'pclass', order=[1, 2, 3])
g.set_axis_labels(x_var='Pclass', y_var='No. Survivors')
```

[image]